# .NET - How To Determine Group Data On String (Delimeter)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have this string data like below:-

```
mydata="KK,23,45,33,56,66,X/TT,01,23,23,56,Y/"
```

Let me remind, this string data can be multiple group where it separately by this character `/`.

Ok. Now on my part I need to slice it more specific from group data string above to push it while loop a group data like this:-

```
While Loop (Group i++)

    '// first 3 items
```

etc: "KK,23,45" sent to function A

```
    '// 2 items after that
```

etc: "33,56" sent to function B

```
    '// last 2 items
```

etc: "66,X" sent to function C

```
    '// remove this charater "/" before continue next group data

    i=i+1
Loop
```

I cannot figure out how to slice it like above while loop. Do you have any idea to solve this problem. 
Thank you on advance for reading and reply my question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can benefit from String.Split method:

- Split the original string by "/" to get your thee items
- Split each part by "," to get the individual items to be sent to methods A, B, and C

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
string[] groups = mydata.Split(new char[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string item in groups)
{
    string[] InnerGroup = item.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    SendToFunctionA(InnerGroup[0] + "," + InnerGroup[1] + "," + InnerGroup[2]);
    SendToFunctionB(InnerGroup[3] + "," + InnerGroup[4]);
    SendToFunctionC(InnerGroup[5] + "," + InnerGroup[6]);
}
```

Or by While Loop:

```
string[] groups = mydata.Split(new char[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int i = 0;
while(i < groups.Length)
{
    string[] InnerGroup = groups[i].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    SendToFunctionA(InnerGroup[0] + "," + InnerGroup[1] + "," + InnerGroup[2]);
    SendToFunctionB(InnerGroup[3] + "," + InnerGroup[4]);
    SendToFunctionC(InnerGroup[5] + "," + InnerGroup[6]);
    i++;
}
```

Above code ignores null values.

If groups have null values, you can use bellow code:

```
string[] groups = mydata.Split(new char[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int i = 0;
while(i < groups.Length)
{
    string[] InnerGroup = groups[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
    SendToFunctionA(InnerGroup[0] + "," + InnerGroup[1] + "," + InnerGroup[2]);
    SendToFunctionB(InnerGroup[3] + "," + InnerGroup[4]);
    SendToFunctionC(InnerGroup[5] + "," + InnerGroup[6]);
    i++;
}
```

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Hello Morteza.M <br /> Your solution given a perfect for my situations and I think this is very simplified and clean code to keep as reference. <br /> I also need to thank  @dasblinkenlight have spirit to helping and kindness to me. <br /> Thanks you so much both of u.

Comment: I just need some clarify if some of data is null what happen to your solutions like this string : mydata="KK,23,45, ,56,66,X/  ,01,23,23,56,Y/" ?

Comment: Thanks. My solution remove null values. If you use " " (space) instead of "" (null), this solution works properly.

Comment: I have edited my solution so that it works by null values.